# Video ref only renders after refresh + function components cannot be given refs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-ref

I have a NEXT JS app that uses the following `VideoPlayer`
component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";    
import { useSocket, useSocketUpdate } from "../Store";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import styles from "../styles/CallPage.module.css";

const VideoPlayer = (props: any) => {
  const {
    isAdmin,
    myVideo,
    userVideo
  }: any = useSocket();
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady && myVideo.current && userVideo.current) {
      myVideo?.current.load();
      userVideo?.current.load();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.grid_container}>
      {stream && (
        <div>
          <video
            className={styles.video}
            playsInline
            muted
            ref={myVideo}
            autoPlay
          />
          <div className={styles.overlay}>
            <h2 className={styles.overlay_h2}>OVERLAY</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      {callAccepted && !callEnded ? (
        <div>
          <video
            className={styles.video}
            playsInline
            ref={userVideo}
            autoPlay
          />
          <div className={styles.overlay}>
            <h2 className={styles.overlay_h2}>OVERLAY2</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        isGuest &&
        !callAccepted && (
          <div className={styles.grid_container}>
            <div className={styles.no_match_content}>
              <h2 className={styles.h2_no_match}>
                Please wait until the host of this room let you in.
              </h2>
              <div className={styles.btn_no_match}></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

The myVideo ref is being retrieved by the useSocket hook which comes from the following `Store` declaration:

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useState,
  useRef,
  useEffect,
  useContext
} from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import Peer from "simple-peer";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
  
const SocketContext = createContext({});
const SocketUpdateContext = createContext({});

const socket = io(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}`);
   
function useSocket() {
  const useSocket = useContext(SocketContext);
  if (useSocket === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useSocket must be used within a SocketProvider");
  }
  return useSocket;
}

function useSocketUpdate() {
  const useSocketUpdate = useContext(SocketUpdateContext);
  if (useSocketUpdate === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useSocketUpdate must be used within a SocketProvider");
  }
  return useSocketUpdate;
}

const ContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
  const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
  const [stream, setStream] = useState<MediaStream>();
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [call, setCall] = useState<any>({});
  const [me, setMe] = useState("");
  const [isAdmin, setAdmin] = useState(false);
  const [isGuest, setGuest] = useState(false);
  const [idToCall, setIdToCall] = useState("");

  const myVideo = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null!);
  const userVideo = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null!);
  const connectionRef = useRef<Peer.Instance>(null!);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);
        if (myVideo.current) {
          myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        }
      });

    socket.on("me", (id) => {
      setMe(id);
    });

    socket.on("callUser", ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);

  const answerCall = () => {
    setCallAccepted(true);

    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on("signal", (data) => {
      socket.emit("answerCall", { signal: data, to: call.from });
    });

    peer.on("stream", (currentStream) => {
      if (userVideo.current) userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
    });

    peer.signal(call.signal);

    connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  const callUser = (id: String) => {
    // setAdmin(false);
    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on("signal", async (data) => {
      socket.emit("callUser", {
        userToCall: id,
        signalData: data,
        from: me,
        name
      });
    });

    peer.on("stream", (currentStream) => {
      if (userVideo.current) userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
    });

    socket.on("callAccepted", (signal) => {
      setCallAccepted(true);

      peer.signal(signal);
    });
    if (connectionRef.current) connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  const leaveCall = () => {
    setCallEnded(true);
    setAdmin(false);
    if (connectionRef.current) connectionRef.current.destroy();
    // if (typeof window !== "undefined") window.location.reload();
    router.push("/home");
  };

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider
      value={{
        call,
        callAccepted,
        myVideo,
        userVideo,
        stream,
        name,
        callEnded,
        me,
        isAdmin,
        router,
        isGuest,
        user,
        isAuthenticated,
        isUnauthenticated,
        isAuthenticating,
        authError,
        idToCall
      }}
    >
      <SocketUpdateContext.Provider
        value={{
          callUser,
          leaveCall,
          answerCall,
          setName,
          setAdmin,
          setGuest,
          logout,
          authenticate,
          signup,
          login,
          setIdToCall
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </SocketUpdateContext.Provider>
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ContextProvider, SocketContext, useSocket, useSocketUpdate };
```

And finally Im rendering the VideoPlayer component in this `CallPage`:

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState, useContext } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/CallPage.module.css";
import Peer from "simple-peer";
import VideoPlayer from "../components/VideoPlayer";

import Page from "../components/UI/Page";
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";    
import { useSocket, useSocketUpdate } from "../Store";
const initialState = [];

const CallPage = () => {
  const { isAdmin, myVideo, isAuthenticated, isUnauthenticated, user }: any =
    useSocket();
  if (isUnauthenticated) {
    return (
      <Page>
        <div className={styles.no_match_content}>
          <h2 className={styles.h2_no_match}>
            Please login first to access a call.
          </h2>
          <div className={styles.btn_no_match}>
            <Link passHref href="/login">
              Login
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Page>
    );
  }
  let alertTimeout = null;

  const [messageList, messageListReducer] = useReducer(
    MessageListReducer,
    initialState
  );    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAdmin) {
      setMeetInfoPopup(true);
    }
  }, []);   
  return (
    <div className={styles.page_container}>
      <VideoPlayer className={styles.video_container} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CallPage;
```

When I click on my home to take me to CallPage, by doing this:

```
<Link
                passHref
                href="/callpage"
              >
                <Button
                  loadingText="Loading"
                  colorScheme="teal"
                  variant="outline"
                  spinnerPlacement="start"
                  className={styles.btn}
                  onClick={handleAdmin}
                >
                  New Meeting
                </Button>
              </Link>
```

The router takes me and everything is rendered but the VideoRef. If I refresh the page it then loads. Do you have any idea why this happens? The devtools throws an error that says that

> function components cannot be given refs

even though Im using such ref in a DOM element as you can see. So I have already ruled out using forwardref. I would really appreciate any help. Im clueless here.

Comment: Function components don't take React refs, you need to forward any passed React refs. What component(s) are having refs passed to them, and which ref is it?

Answer (score 0):

One idea...

```
useEffect(() => { 
 if (router.isReady && myVideo.current && userVideo.current) {
    myVideo?.current.load();
    userVideo?.current.load();
  }
}, []);
```

Your hook has an empty dependency array. It's certainly possible that on first render the `router.isReady` returns false. You should pass `router.isReady` to the dependency array.

Additionally your CallPage function is conditionally running an effect. That effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isAdmin) {
    setMeetInfoPopup(true);
  }
}, []);
```

should also pass `isAdmin` and whatever the VALUE of the `setMeetInfoPopup` setter is into the dependency array. Assuming the `useState` value for that setter is called `meetInfoPopup`, the hook should actually read like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isAdmin && !meetInfoPopup) {
    setMeetInfoPopup(true);
  }
}, [isAdmin, meetInfoPopup]);
```